# Java Swing Dialog issue

Tags: java, swing, dialog

When pressed the "Inregistrare" button a dialog pops, requesting the user to enter a password (set to "qwerty"). I want it keep displaying dialogs until the password is correct. The method is the following:

```
private void ItemInregistrareActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    JOptionPane dialog = new JOptionPane();
    dialog.setWantsInput(true);

    dialog.showInputDialog("Password please:");

    while(dialog.getInputValue()!="qwerty")
        dialog.showInputDialog("Mai baga o fisa.");       

    ItemInregistrare.setEnabled(false);
    ItemOpen.setEnabled(true);
    ItemSave.setEnabled(true);

}
```

The problem is it never gets out of the while, even if the password is correct. Any tips?

Comment: You need to assign the String returned from the dialog to a String variable, and then compare using equals

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) for a better approach then closing/showing the dialog every time the password is invalid. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some variable are correct, others are not. Be consistent and follow Java conventions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is a static method and does not need any instance of `JOptionPane`. Moreover, it already returns the entered value or `null` if user pressed Cancel. So you don't need to call `dialog.getInputValue()`.

You could try something like this:

```
String pwd;
do {
    pwd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password please:");
} while (pwd != null && !pwd.equals("qwerty"));
if (pwd == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You pressed cancel");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password is correct");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using 
`!dialog.getInputValue().equals("qwerty")` 
to compare strings